# Script not working on brackets but working on this web console

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know why, but when I try to use "app.js" file (which contains 2 scripts) in brackets, only one of them works, but, on this website's console both of the scripts work at the time, does anyone know why?
Thanks!

(The two scripts are the same code, but I just changed some names, they are from internet, I have no idea about js).

```js
const togglePassword1 = document.querySelector('#togglePassword1');
const password1 = document.querySelector('#password1');

togglePassword1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // toggle the type attribute
  const type = password1.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
  password1.setAttribute('type', type);
  // toggle the eye / eye slash icon
  this.classList.toggle('bi-eye');
});

const togglePassword2 = document.querySelector('#togglePassword2');
const password2 = document.querySelector('#password2');

togglePassword2.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // toggle the type attribute
  const type = password2.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
  password2.setAttribute('type', type);
  // toggle the eye / eye slash icon
  this.classList.toggle('bi-eye');
});
```

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background-color: #F5BED8;
    width: 100%;
}

.password1 i {
    margin-left: -30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.password2 i {
    margin-left: -30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.password_tittle{
    font-family: 'montserrat';
    font-size:1.4em;
    font-weight: 550;
    color: #fcecf5;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px
}

.password_input{
    width:420px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px  #2d9fd9;
}
.password_input::placeholder{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-family: 'montserrat';
    font-weight:100;
    font-style: italic;
}

.confirm_password_input{
    width:420px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px  #2d9fd9;
}
.confirm_password_input::placeholder{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-family: 'montserrat';
    font-weight:100;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div class="password1">
                        
                    <p class="password_tittle">Password</p>

                        <input class="password_input" type="password" name="password" id="password1" placeholder="Password..." />
                        <i class="bi bi-eye-slash fa-lg" id="togglePassword1"></i>

                        <script type='text/javascript' src="app.js"></script>

                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="password2">
                        
                        <p class="password_tittle">Confirm Password</p>

                        <input class="confirm_password_input" type="password" name="password" id="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password..." />
                        <i class="bi bi-eye-slash fa-lg" id="togglePassword2"></i>
                        
                    </div>
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce

Comment: how do I solve that?

Comment: is your app.js file in the same folder of the html file?

Comment: yes, should i put all the js files on another folder?

Comment: No, but check in your browser console if you have some error about your js file, or try to put your js file just before the end of the body tag

Comment: it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null", it is on the 15th line of the js, but i don't know how to fix that, do u have any idea of how to do it?

Comment: Ok the error is clear, the console gives you the line of the error, so check it if your const variable are setted

Comment: I don't wanna bother you but...How do i do that? I have 0% idea about js

Comment: I've reproduce your errore, Just put your `<script type='text/javascript' src="app.js"></script>` before `</body>` tag and all works fine